# How to Retweet the latest Tweet of a certain account?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I need to be able to Retweet the latest Tweet from a certain Twitter account, but have an issue getting the Tweet ID of the latest post automatically. For example, I have used the `api.retweet()` function, but I need to know what to enter into this function, as well as how to pull the ID from the latest Tweet. **This is using the Tweepy module (Python Twitter Module).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`API.user_timeline`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.2.0/api.html#tweepy.API.user_timeline) to retrieve their latest Tweet and the `id` attribute of that [`Status`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.2.0/models.html#tweepy.models.Status)/[Tweet object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) representing their most recent Tweet.